# Retrieving argument values from an object instance

Tags: python

If I have an instance of class A, is there anyway to know what arguments were used to instantiate that instance?

I looked up the `inspect` module, and there are tools that a *sooo* close, but not quite right.  For instance, the `inspect.getargvalues(frame)` *almost* works, except you can only get the `frame` from within the class itself. I want to get these after-the-fact.

Ideally, what I want is:

> instance_a = ClassA(arguments)
>
> inspect.get_values_set_to_the_init(instance_a)

I *don't* want to have to save the arguments from within the **init** statement if avoidable.

I should say the reason I want this in case there is a completely different approach:  I want to be able to recreate a 'replica' of the object by saving the arguments (using my imaginary function above), then instantiating a new object by passing in exactly the same arguments to **init**.  Pickle, Shelve and Marshall don't work since my object is apparently unserializable.

Comment: Why would you not be able to retrieve the state of an object you create from a class you define?

Comment: A much simpler solution than inspect would be to use a class decorator to grab the arguments to init at instantiation time.  However, I completely agree with Ignacio - WHY do you need this?

Comment: User defined objects are frequently pickleable -- What errors do you get when you try?

Comment: I added the 'why' at the bottom of my Q.  I want to create a 'replica' object and need to know what values were sent to the init.  The decorator option comes up in Google, but is a bit beyond my python at the moment...could you elaborate?

Comment: @mgilson: my object is a subclass of a ``dict`` with a large number of additional methods.  I was totally stone walled with errors in all my pickle/shelve/marshall attempts.  I don't even remember the errors anymore.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I'm not totally sure why you think this is trivial...do you suggest that I save the arguments to some hidden attribute in my object, like instance_a._init_args?  If so, the reason is that ClassA is a subclass that will be user written, and i don't want to force users to follow a bunch of 'rules' when creating their subclasses.

Comment: You can _usually_ make an object serializable by removing some objects from the serialized result.  FWIW, I would use Pickle.  That doesn't really help object creation over objects you have no control over, but you'll never solve that.  The only thing you can do is create a base class and tell users "thou shalt inherit from this base class".  That doesn't guarantee anything, however, since they can (and probably will) add members that aren't serializable (e.g. file handles).  Even if you saved base-class __init__ params, you could save child class __init__ params.